# C# Write to file using StreamWriter with ANSI encoding doesn't work

Tags: c#, encoding, streamwriter, ansi

I want to write to text file with ANSI encoding. Code looks like below:

```
string text = "abc123";
string filePath = "C:\\Data\\MyFile.csv";

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.Default))
{
    sw.Write(text);
}
```

When I open result file with Notepad++ and click on 'Encoding' button on menu then there is always 'UTF-8 (without BOM)' which I want to avoid. 
I tried to choose option 'convert to ANSI', but after save of file and reopen it's still 'UTF-8.

I am stuck with this issue for long time, could anyone give some hint ?

Comment: For ANSI characters, those are completely identical.  You don't actually have a problem (except the use of ANSI; you should use UTF8).

Comment: It's not at all clear that there's anything wrong. My guess is that all the text is ASCII - Notepad++ is basically just guessing the encoding, and UTF-8 is a perfectly reasonable guess.

Comment: use classic notepad. It also has the encoding options in its "save as" dialog and you can use that to check. or better, use a binary viewer (for example Visual Studio's integrated one) to see if there is any multi-byte character, byte order mark or such present in the file. `Encoding.Default` relies on the `GetACP` [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx) and can be different on other computers. If you want to be sure, choose a specific ANSI code page.

Comment: Then why are you using  Encoding.Default instead of Encoding.ASCII or  Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with StreamWriter, it is how Notepad++ works. You can easily see it yourself. Just open classic windows Notepad, type "test" and "save as" with ANSI encoding. Then open in Notepad++ - it will recognize encoding as UTF8.

Comment: this is not entirely true. As long as you use only characters used in the english language, your statement regarding Notepadd++ recognition is true. However, as soon as you use a character from a different language (say, `ä` or `é`), Notepad++ will recognize the file as ANSI and if you choose UTF-8 the 'special' characters will show up as unprintable characters. The real issue is to choose default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you export text containing special characters, for example 'é', Notepadd++ will then show the encoding as ANSI instead of UTF-8.

```
string text = "éçë";
```